# Bootstrap dropdown not showing fully

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have added a bootstrap framework to a new theme in WordPress and my dropdown is not shown fully. I have tried with `z-index` but still nothing. Can anyone help me.

Thanks!

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- container-fluid -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!-- do not remove these, this will be visible on the mobile devices -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!-- do not remove these, this will be visible on the mobile devices -->
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <!-- do not remove these, this will be visible on the mobile devices -->
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>">                
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/main_logo.png" alt="beekeeper-design-studio-logo.png" title="Beekeeper Design Studio Logo"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-right">
            <?php /* for Bootstrap navbar use this php from -  https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker */
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    // name of the menu which you created in wp admin panel 
                    'menu'              => 'wp-primary-menu',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1', // to collapse the navbar in responsive
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav', // ul menu class
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker() //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                    ));
            ?>                
        </div>
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here's the HTML output of this code.

[image]

The dropdown is not behind or forward it is actually not going outside the navbar container. Increasing the navbar height shows the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Where is HTML??

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers i have updated with the HTML code.

Comment: That additional code is not terribly helpful, since the generated HTML is hidden behind a PHP function that we have no familiarity with. Please update your question to show the generated markup, no the PHP.

Comment: @Serlite I have updated the code with the generated HTML output. Iam not sure it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

### 01 2023 [Updated]

It is working. The problem is with the `overflow` in the `navbar` class.
I set it to `overflow: visible' it is working now.

```css
.navbar-default {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index of the hidden element(I'm playing with 1000, but use the smallest you can).

```
.dropdown-menu{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Not working. I tried all kinds of numbers but still the same issue. What i can able to see is that the dropdown is not behind or front, it is actually inside the navbar. if i expand the navbar i can able to see it.

Comment: I found the solution buddy, thank for your time. I have added the answer above.

Comment: Np. Glad you made it ;)